# Container does not stretch beyond window width

Tags: html, css

I am suffering the same problem another StackOverflow user asked here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493425/background-image-doesnt-repeat-when-browser-window-is-smaller-than-content).
The solution was to use the following CSS on the container (div):

```
display:table;
width:100%;
```

However, I have a border at the bottom of my div and now there is a gap between the content of the div and the border.

Does anyone know how to remove this gap?

***Edit:***

The CSS of the container:

```
background-image:url('images/header.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
border-bottom-color:black;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-bottom-width:5px;
font-size:small;
font-weight:bold;
```

It may also be worth me adding that inside this container is another div with the following CSS:

```
#header
{
clear:both;
height:50px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:900px;
}

#header > *
{
float:left;
}
```

And some HTML:

```
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is your table in absolute positon or your div?  can you put some html and CSS for best understanding?

Comment: Added the CSS (excluding the 'display' and 'width' properties) of the container.

Comment: Did you try to put more height to your header?

Comment: small HTML will be aprecialte

Comment: in your header CSS I see there is the ;  missing at the end of your height.

Comment: I tried adding more height to the header but the problem remains - the header just gets larger but the gap remains the same.

Comment: Oh that missing ; is not in the code. I must have accidentally deleted it whilst editing the post.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot or a link where I can see, it. On my side the only thing I can see is a black line. it is hard to see the gaps in my imagination :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16737/discussion-between-manuel-choucino-and-theboss)

Comment: I found the solution to the problem - I had an inline element within the child div and that was causing it to be pushed down (an invisible gap) which I suppose was created from the line height.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
```