# Site width over a html code

Tags: html, css, width, overflow, resolution

My problem is hard to explain (especially when knowledge of English is at the primary level)

My test site: ----
On page is over than html code, you can see scroll to right. (On small resolution)
Picture of this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtaBl.jpg

How to fix that problem ?

If, something is not clear, and somebody don't understand my problem please ask.

(I am not giving CSS becouse is too much of code, so everything is in source code of website)

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by overflow-x is over than html code. Sounds like a song: "My Bonnie is over the ocean.."

Comment: are you try to do a Responsive website?

Comment: This should help: http://i.imgur.com/arCoPt7.png

Comment: I dont want to make responsive website. I want only remove this white "something" outside website html.

Comment: something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493425/background-image-doesnt-repeat-when-browser-window-is-smaller-than-content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is the class statystyki inside the class menu.
in your p element you have width:100% and float left and the other elements right.
So you exceed the total width of 100%.

Try to make a width that dont exceed the 100% and also is best if you clear the floats.

Comment: thank you very much! something like this fix my problem!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra margins and check all the divs width.
or simply add 
this style to your body.

```
body {

    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

http://haleem.itspiders.net/