# Not working background-repeat for mobile/tablet screen

Tags: html, css, background, responsive-design, background-repeat

I have a background pattern which I want to be repeated both vertically and horizontally. I use `background-repeat:repeat;` for `body` and it works fine, but when I resize the page (using Viewport Resizer) to a mobile/tablet screen a part of the background becomes white. What can be causing the problem?

Comment: Do you have a min-width set? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493425/background-image-doesnt-repeat-when-browser-window-is-smaller-than-content

Comment: No, I haven't, but thanks for trying to help! :)